# Seperate a UILabel text to three different UILabels

Tags: ios, swift

i am not really sure if the title meets what i want, but i have a `label` with a bunch of sentences, i want to separate each one of them to a different `UILabel`

Here's my code

```
   var s: [String] = []
   for (i, pred) in results.enumerated() {
    let latLongArr = pred.0.components(separatedBy: "\t")
    myLatitude = latLongArr[1]
    myLongitude = latLongArr[2]
    s.append(String(format: "%d: %@ %@ (%3.2f%%)", i + 1, myLatitude, myLongitude, pred.1 * 100))
    places[i].title = String(i+1)
    places[i].coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(myLatitude)!, longitude: CLLocationDegrees(myLongitude)!)
}
predictionLabel.text = s.joined(separator: "\n") // one label
```

and the UILabel text looks something like this

```
Prediction 1: latitude longitude // first sentence
(probability%)
Prediction 2: latitude longitude // second
(probability%)
Prediction 3: latitude longitude // third
(probability%)
```

Thank you

## EDIT

i've created three labels and tried this code, unfortunately it gives the first result

```
    self.predict1.text = s.joined(separator: "\n")
    self.predict2.text = s.joined(separator: "\n")
    self.predict3.text = s.joined(separator: "\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you set [numberOfLines](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620539-numberoflines) on the label to 0 and [lineBreakMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620525-linebreakmode) to .[byWordWrapping](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsparagraphstyle.linebreakmode) or you make a vertical statckview, instantiate a label for each string, and add the label to the stackview's [arrangedSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview/1616227-addarrangedsubview).

**EDIT**
Now that I look at your code the real problem is the line **let latLongArr = pred.0.components(separatedBy: "\t")**.  Most likely your data has trailing newlines in it and you need to kill the trailing newlines after the longitude.

```
   var s: [String] = []
   for (i, pred) in results.enumerated() {
    let latLongArr = pred.0.components(separatedBy: "\t").replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "")
    myLatitude = latLongArr[1]
    myLongitude = latLongArr[2]
    s.append(String(format: "%d: %@ %@ (%3.2f%%)", i + 1, myLatitude, myLongitude, pred.1 * 100))
    places[i].title = String(i+1)
    places[i].coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(myLatitude)!, longitude: CLLocationDegrees(myLongitude)!)
}
```

Comment: `instantiate a label for each string` Im new to swift, can you tell me more about this one